# A Question about order of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be commutative ring with unity and $R[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one variable for a  non zero $f=\sum _{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n$, define $D(f)$  to be the smallest n such that $a_n \neq 0$. Also $D(0)=+\infty$ . Then which of the following are statements is/are true?

1) $D(f+g)\geq \min\{D(f),D(g)\} $

2) $D(fg) \geq D(f)+D(g)$

3) $D(f+g)=\min(D(f),D(g)) $, if $D(f)\neq D(g)$

4) $D(fg)=D(f)+D(g)$, if $R$ is an integral domain

4 is obviously true when R is integral domain but i am not sure about 1, 2, 3

Comment: $D(f)$ is not the *degree* of $f$ but its *order* (the degree of its initial term when the polynomial is written by increasing powers).

Comment: Start from $f=X^{D(f)}f_1$ with $D(f_1)=0$.

Comment: For instance, what you get for $f=g=\hat 2X$ in $\mathbb Z_4[X]$?

Comment: If $R \not = \mathbb{R}$ or any other subset of $\mathbb{R}$, how do you define the relation $\leq$ ? I mean you question works on an arbitrary ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $D(f)=m$ and $D(g)=n$,

1) Because $0+0=0$ in any ring, all the terms in $f+g$ with degree less than $min\{m,n\}$ will be $0$. So, it's true.

2) Because $0.a=0$ for all $a\in R$,

All the terms in $fg$ with degree less than $m+n$ will be the sum of the multiplications of the terms of f and g where either the degree of the term from f is less than $m$ or the degree of the term from g is less than $n$ which means  $0.a=0$ or $a.0=0$. So, $D(fg) \geq m+n$.

3) Without lost of generality, assume $m\gt n$.

Then as in the first one, all the terms of $f+g$ with degree less than $n$ is $0$. Because the term of $f$ with degree $n$ is $0$ and $0+a=a$ for all $a\in R$, the coefficient of the term of $f+g$ with degree n is equal to the coefficient of the term of $g$ with degree n which is nonzero. So $D(f+g)=n=min\{m,n\}$.